Confused about a counting problem
This question is reproduced from a text by Sheldon Ross:

Example 5k.  A football team consists of $20$ offensive and $20$ defensive players.  The players are to be paired in groups of $2$ for the purpose of determining roommates.  If the pairing is done at random, what is the probability that there are no offensive-defensive roommate pairs?  What is the probability that there are $2i$ offensive-defensive roommate pairs, $i = 1, 2, \ldots, 10$?


Solution.  There are $$\binom{40}{2, 2, \ldots, 2} = \frac{40!}{(2!)^{20}}$$ ways of dividing the $40$ players into $20$ ordered pairs of two each.  [That is, there are $40!/2^{20}$ ways of dividing the players into a first pair, a second pair, and so on.]  Hence there are $40!/(2^{20} \cdot 20!)$ ways of dividing the players into (unordered) pairs of $2$ each.  Furthermore, since a division will result in no offensive-defensive pairs if the offensive (and defensive) players are paired among themselves, it follows that there are $(20!/(2^{10} \cdot 10!))^2$ such divisions.  Hence the probability of no offensive-defensive roommate pairs, call it $P_0$, is given by $$P_0 = \frac{\left(\frac{20!}{2^{10} 10!}\right)^2}{\frac{40!}{2^{20} 20!}} = \frac{(20!)^3}{(10!)^2(40!)}.$$  To determine $P_{2i}$, the probability that there are $2i$ offensive-defensive pairs, we first note that there are $\displaystyle \binom{20}{2i}^2$ ways of selecting the $2i$ offensive players and the $2i$ defensive players who are to be in the offensive-defensive pairs.  These $4i$ players can then be paired up into $(2i)!$ possible offensive-defensive pairs.  (This is so because the first offensive can be paired with any of the $2i$ defensives, the second offensive can with any of the remaining $2i-1$ defensives, and so on.)  As the remaining $20-2i$ offensives (and defensives) must be paired among themselves, it follows that there are $$\binom{20}{2i}^2 (2i)! \left(\frac{(20-2i)!}{2^{10-i}(10-i)!}\right)^2$$

[Editor's note:  the remainder of the text of the solution has been cut off.]

Actually I'm a bit confused about the solution to the first part of the problem which asks for no offensive-defensive pairs. To be specific I don't understand why do we divide by 10!  ; I know it's because we want to cancel out the permutation of the groups but like we have 20 groups and this cancelation doesn't account for all of them right? we why don't we just divide by 20!?

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

As @JoséCarlosSantos says, one shouldn’t be made to follow a link to find out what a question is or means.

One suggestion:  the problem makes sense for smaller groups.  Suppose you had a $4$ player team, $2$ offense, two defense.  In that case, you should be able to write out everything completely.  That should confirm or refute the factor in question.  Even a $6$ player team might not be that hard to write out.

@lulu Nice suggestion, I have done it and I have find out that my approach leads to an invalid result; But still I Don't get it why it leads to an wrong answer.

The are considering the subcase where the defensives are paired up and the offenses are teamed up.  So you have $10$ (not $20$) pairs of offensive players and $10$ (not $20$) pairs of defensive players.  So you have $\frac{20!}{2^{10}10!}$ ways to team up the $20$ defensive players into $10$ pairs, and $\frac{20!}{2^{10}10!}$ to team up the $20$ offensive players into $10$ pairs.  And that means you have $\frac{20!}{2^{10}10!}\times \frac{20!}{2^{10}10!}=[\frac{20!}{2^{10}10!}]^2$ ways to match the forty players into $10$ pairs of defense and $10$ pairs of offense.

@VacationDue20000 I have transcribed the text contained in the image provided in an earlier edit; however, it is incomplete.  Please provide the remainder of the relevant text and the complete title of the book from which it was obtained.

Thanks mate @heropup

The $10!$ comes up when trying to figure out how many pairings there are when only offense-offense and defense-defense pairings are allowed. Then there are still $20$ pairings, but they partition into $10$ pairings between $2$ offense players only and $10$ pairings between 2 defense players only.
In this case, we have partitioned the problem into 2 totally distinct and unrelated parts. What pairings are decided among the offense players has no bearing at all on what pairings are chosen among the defense players, and vice versa.
Trying to switch a defense-defensive pair with an offense-offense pair would result, when looking at the pairings of the offensive players, in 9 pairings of offense players and 1 pairing of defense players. But such a result doesn't make sense when considering only pairings of offensive players. That's why you can't allow such a permutation here.
In the original part where you can mix all players, that isn't true. Since you consider all players together, switching any 2 selected pairs of players results in a valid result, so you have to factor out the whole $20!$.

Exactly right! Let me add a bit more to clarify. We divide by a factorial like 20! in the denominator to avoid counting the same group twice, ensuring each unique group is only counted once. However, we don’t divide the numerator by the same factor because it's impossible to get a group of OO while we're grouping DD's, So we should just make sure that a permutation of the OO groups doesn't get counted twice, Thus we just divide by the number of the possible OO groups which is 10!. The same would be true when grouping DD's.

The whole point is that we are just counting the number of possible pairs without bothering about the pairs' position in the line or the order within a pair,
that is how we get $\dfrac{40!}{2^{20}\cdot 20!}$ when we form all possible pairs
So if we form only offensive pairs, we will get $\dfrac{20!}{2^{10}\cdot 10!}$
Ditto for defensive pairs, $\dfrac{20!}{2^{10}\cdot 10!}$
And  combining the two using the multiplication principle,
$$\dfrac{20!}{2^{10}\cdot 10!}\cdot\dfrac{20!}{2^{10}\cdot 10!} = \left[\dfrac{20!}{2^{10}\cdot 10!}\right]$$
PS:
A much cleaner way of deriving the number of possible pairs from $2n$ distinct objects is to realise that choosing sequentially, the first object picked can be paired in $(2n-1)$ ways, the next picked can be paired in $(2n-3)$ ways, etc, thus $(2n-1)(2n-3)(2n-5)...1$ This skipping by two multiplication is called the double factorial,
so total possible # of pairings $= (2n-1)!!$
When we pair offense and defence separately, the pairings will be $(n-1)!!$ for each part, which combined using the multiplication principle, will become $[(n-1)!!]^2$
and $Pr = \dfrac{[(n-1)!!]^2}{(2n-1)!!}$
Looking at it this way should make it much easier to understand.
Here is a check for $2n = 40$ for this/book formula

We can answer the question by breaking it into a series of smaller questions and combining.  Your misunderstanding begins in question 4 below.
1:  How many ways are there to combine $40$ players into pairs where the roommates in the pairs are listed in order, and the pairs are listed in order.
Answer:  There are $40!$ ways to order the $40$ players.  Now just pair them off in the order the were listed: Player 1 bunks with player 2, 3 with 4, etc.
2: How many ways where the order of the roommates in the pairs don't matter but the listing of of the pairs in order does.  [BTW... IMO the text showed poor judgement in refering to the ordered list of pairs as "ordered pairs".  In math an "ordered pair means something entirely different. Namely, a pair where the order within the pair matters.]
Answer: Well, in answer 1, we have $40!$ ways to make $20$ pairs.  For each pair there are $2$ ways to order the roommates so if order doesn't matter we must divide by $2$ for each pair.  There are $20$ pairs so we must divide by $2^{20}$ so the answer is: $\frac{40!}{2^{20}}$.
3: How many ways are there to do this were the order of the list of pairs doesn't matter.
Answer: For each list of $20$ pairs, there are $20!$ ways to order those specific $20$ pairs so we must divide the answer to question 3 by $20!$.  The answer is $\frac {40!}{2^{20}20!}$.
Question 4: How many ways are there to pair of the defensive players into pairs where order within the pairs and the order of the listing of the pairs don't matter.  [I think you question comes that you didn't really understand this is what is being done, and being asked for.]
Answer:  You have $20$ defensive plays and you want $10$ pairs.  We are for now completely ignoring the offensive players.  By the exact same reasoning of questions 1 through 3 above, the answer is easily seen to be: $\frac {20!}{2^{10}10!}$.
(We are dividing by $10!$ (and not $20!$) because we have only $10$ pairs of defensive players)
Okay, that answers your question but to continue solving the problem
5: How many ways to pair up the offensive players into roommates.
Answer: same as to question 4; $\frac {20!}{2^{10}10!}$
6: How many ways to team up all $40$ players so there are no offensive-defensive pairs.
Answer: To have no offensive defensive pairs, we must have the defensive players all paired up with each other--There are $\frac {20!}{2^{10}10!}$ to do that-- and the offensive players are all roommated together-- there are $\frac {20!}{2^{10}10!}$ to do that.  So there are $\frac {20!}{2^{10}10!} \times \frac {20!}{2^{10}10!} =(\frac {20!}{2^{10}10!} )^2$ ways to do that.
Finally 7: What is the probability of no offensive-defensive pairs.
Answer: Number of ways to have no offensive-defensive pairs divided by entire number of ways = $\frac {(\frac {20!}{2^{10}10!} )^2}{\frac {40!}{2^{20}20!}}$.

No understand the question that you mentioned, and at total there are 20 pairs that we have to cancel out the permutation of.
